# Deploying Data with containers across multiple environments

Tags: docker, deployment, containers, devops, cicd

I wondered if I could pick your brains regarding deploying data across environments with containers... I have a hard time understanding the "standard" deployment process.

Let me set the scene:
You're running a CMS on your local development environment and you have two containers - a database container that runs MySQL and links to a volume (that stores the data), and the CMS container that links to it. All fine.

Now, I can deploy through GitLab/GitHub CI/CD by pushing any code changes to the repo in the CMS container - which will rebuild an image and push it to a 'Staging' environment (via a container registry). That's fine too.
Here's the issue - what's the standard accepted way of deploying the DATA in the database to the 'Staging' environment? Particularly through CI/CD?

I understand that having a cloudDB is best practice on staging/production, which again, is totally ok for me to do, but short of writing some Bash scripts to sqldump and rsync the data, I can't see how people do it with standard CI/CD pipelines.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Usually I work with test data in development and I don't want to deploy that to production. If I have things that I need to run against the production database, I make a migration script that I store with the code and run against the production database when I deploy the code.

Comment: Hey Hans, thanks for the reply! It's all actually content data. Using the CMS as an example - it would be all the blog post content or post content. All the layout changes and page settings, etc... Stuff that perhaps a content-manager would add. So not something that you could create a migration file for (like laravel does with it's database structure).

I like the idea of including the data within the CI/CD pipeline process - but I've just not really seen a solid definitive answer to how most people do it.